# Get value from detect colour python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

For my project, I want to control an RC car to avoid red obstacles using a webcam camera running `Raspberry Pi`.

I can control my RC car, but I don't know much about `openCV`. I can also detect selected colours using the webcam, but I do not know how to get the colour value from the image to my RC car.

The issue that I am having is that my car does not know that a blue object is in front of the camera.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
cap = cv2.videoCapture(0)
while(1):
# take each frame
_,frame=cap.read()

#convert BGR to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#define range of blue color in HSV
lower_blue = np.array([160,50,50],dtype=np.uint8)
uper_blue np.array([179,255,255],dtype=np.uint8)

#Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_blue,upper_blue)

cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
k=cv2.waitKey(5) &0xFF
if k == 27 :
   break
cv2.destroyAllwindows()
```

Comment: Display `mask` on a window and you will see that objects in it are those defined between the **range** you specified. After that, iterating on the pixels of this image will give inform the specific **(x,y)** coordinates of those objects, so you can turn your robot to the other way.

Comment: thank you sir 
but which fuction or command shall i use to iterating pixels to get x and y coordinate 
if there any keyword for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the color values using:

```
values = img[100,100]
```

You have to Check if Mask is 255 (Pixel in Range) and get the color from your image (hsv).

To iterate over the image you can use:

```
img.shape
```

which returns rows, columns, and channels.

In total you get something like:

```
row, col, chan = img.shape
for r in row:
    for c in col:
        if mask[r,c] == 255:
            print img[r,c]
```

You can find more information in the [OpenCV Python Tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html).